# How to add an attribute to a node so it is the first one

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have a Nokogiri xml node:

```
node = <word n='ab' v='cd'>something</word>
```

I want to add an attribute:

```
node['p']='ef'
```

but in such a way that it 'shows' the first in the list of attributes, like

```
node = <word p='ef' n='ab' v='cd'>something</word>
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Why is the order of attributes important to you?  XML is designed in such a way that it shouldn't matter.

Comment: I am placing as attributes the possible 'part of speech' of the word, the order denotes the certitude (probability of getting the right pos). In this way, the first attribute is, of all the possible ones, the most probable. Then, an algorithm filters out the attributes according to how different words interact among them.

Comment: A lot of people would think it's a really bad idea to require a specific ordering of attributes. You should consider adding additional data that can be used to sort them, or re-structure your XML, as introducing this requirement would make life very difficult for people consuming it as a lot of XML reading libraries ignore ordering.

Comment: As Mike says. XML doesn't care about order of attributes, as such, any XML parser also may not respect this order. But if you are controlling the creation of the XML, and the parsing, I suggest you may have to handroll the xml generation.

Comment: Or maybe you are thinking of this wrong. Perhaps you need a more complicated structure. `<word><priorities><p>ef</p><n>ab</n><v>cd</v></properties><content>something</content></word>`

Comment: As said before, XML does not support ordering of the attributes. YOU can assign some attribute to each parameter of a particular tag by breaking the tag into sub-nodes, then adding a precedence or weighting attribute to those. By themselves, parameter ordering has no significance, and in XML it will not be preserved by a parser, and most likely, will not be available to you when searching/traversing the DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any XML serializer that allows you to control the order of attributes (except by accident, relying on undocumented features of a product). It shouldn't matter; the order is only cosmetic.

When you say "the order denotes the certitude" this is very worrying, because you are attaching meaning to the order of attributes when XML is very clear that the order will in general not be maintained. You need to redesign your XML to find a different way to capture this information.

Comment: Thanks to all the responses. I understand now and I'll re-structure the code to avoid using the order of attributes.